# Any alternative for jsPanel?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am working on a project which is in complete stage. Client wants to open some pages as floating panels with minimize, maximize and close options(not in new window or new tab) . I found jsPanel which fits my requiremnt but I have to do lots of changes with my files to fit for jsPanel. Is there any other js / plugin which works like jsPanel, with easy implementation on my existing code.

Comment: You probably won't find a plugin that works without the need to make some changes to your existing code. Some time ago I tried to find one myself and didn't find anything fitting my needs (at least no free and open source tool). So I created my own plugin which is ... jsPanel. So if you decide to give jsPanel a try I'm willing to help as good as I can ...

Comment: @Flyer53 thanks for your response, Client changed his mind and move over from floating panels. Will seek help from you if need.